# Google Sheets sidebar stopped loading about 1 hour ago

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sidebar that is opened using an onLoad() trigger in Google sheets. Up until about an hour ago, it was working fine. Now, it opens and is completely blank. In the console, the head and body tags were completely empty and I had the following error messages:
[image: These are the error messages]

I've tried disabling some extensions that could've been causing problems, but that hasn't seemed to do anything.
Does anyone know what could be going on? Any insight is appreciated

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:191640&s=created_time:desc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the issue was resolved from the comments section, in order to provide a proper response to the question.

It would also be used to clarify the comment. If you are experiencing this particular error or alert and you considered it is a bug. You should be able to follow the link to share the logs and report the issue

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues

You can use the keyword or search by:

> refused to load script it violates the following

From different reviews of this error, it is generally due to the browser or the local host of the application. You can find some other example and issue reporting options over the references section.

**Reference**

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1054624
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1220994